# Expected measure of a ball in a probability space with a metric

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, metric-spaces, geometric-measure-theory, point-processes

Assume we are given a probability space $(\mathbb{X}, \mathcal{X}, \mathbb Q)$ and a measurable distance function defined on it $d:\mathbb{X}\times \mathbb{X}\to \mathbb{R}^+\cup\{0\}$ that conforms to the usual definition of distance on metric spaces. I am trying to understand (in lay terms) the "expected value of the measure of a ball with fixed radius $r> 0$ centered at a randomly chosen point in $\mathbb{X}$ with measure $\mathbb{Q}$". That is more formally
\begin{equation}
\int_{\mathbb{X} }q(x)\mathbb{Q}(\mathrm{d}x)  
\end{equation}
where $q(x) = \mathbb{Q}(B(x,r))$ and $B(x,r) = \{y\in \mathbb{X}: d(x,y)\leq r\} $. The first thing to ask here is if $q(x)$ is measurable but for now I assume $\mathcal{X}$ is large enough that it is.

My problem originates from this question: "find a lower bound for the probability that a randomly chosen iid set of points in a space are close-by". I am wondering what assumptions are needed from $\mathbb{Q}$ and $d$ such that this can be lower bounded. Of course I would not expect a bound valid for all $\mathbb{Q}$ and $d$ but any tip about how to treat this integral (or you know if anybody thought about this before and gave it a name so I can search) would be helpful. The trivial bound $\inf_{x\in\mathbb X} \mathbb{Q}(B(x,r))$ is not useful for my purposes.

Comment: crossposted: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/380396/

Answer (score 0):

How is it defined the probability density function $\mathbb{Q}$? Is it discrete or continuous?

If it's continuous then $\lim_{r\rightarrow0}\int_{B_r}q(x)dx=0$

And if it's discrete then $\lim_{r\rightarrow0}\int_{B_r}q(x)dx=q(y)$

Comment: I don't want to make the assumption that $\mathbb{Q}$ has a density, unless I have to. What is $y$ in your second equation? Note $x$ itself is random here.

Comment: y is the center of the ball. $B(x,r) = \{y\in \mathbb{X}: d(x,y)\leq r\}$. And every probability function (a probability space is defined by a set a $\sigma$-algebra and a probability function) has a density (a sum of a discrete function + continuous function, doing the derivative in the case of a continuous funtion and calculating the difference of the limits from the right and left side in the case of the discrete jumps)